# omnicomplete in vim with shift-tab not working?

Tags: vim, omnicomplete

Im trying to get vim to allow me to circle through the autocomplete popup list with the tab key. It works fine for tab but not for s-tab (shift-tab).
It seems like shift-tab somehow canceles the autocomplete menu before applying C-P

Anyone got any ideas?

```
function InsertTabWrapper(direction)
  if pumvisible()
    if "forward" == a:direction
      return "\<C-N>"
    else
      return "\<C-P>"
    endif
  endif
  let col = col('.') - 1
  if !col || getline('.')[col - 1] !~ '\k' 
    return "\<tab>"
  else
    return "\<c-x>\<c-o>"
  endif
endfunction

inoremap <tab> <c-r>=InsertTabWrapper("forward")<cr>
inoremap <s-tab> <c-r>InsertTabWrapper("backward")<cr>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You missed the equal sign "=" after `<c-r>` for the `<s-tab>` mapping.

However, I would suggest doing it like this:

```
function! InsertTabWrapper()
  if pumvisible()
    return "\<c-n>"
  endif
  let col = col('.') - 1
  if !col || getline('.')[col - 1] !~ '\k'
    return "\<tab>"
  else
    return "\<c-x>\<c-o>"
  endif
endfunction
inoremap <expr><tab> InsertTabWrapper()
inoremap <expr><s-tab> pumvisible()?"\<c-p>":"\<c-d>"
```

1. Use `<expr>` mapping. It's nicer to see and clearer (many people don't know about `<c-r>=` things.
2. Mapping `<s-tab>` like this and you can do unindent in insertmode.

Comment: Seems as if someone was impressed by your code: http://moviecode.tumblr.com/post/76605632708/the-intro-sequence-of-the-anime-time-of-eve

Comment: OMG! I saw the post on the RSS feed, but didn't realized that's from my answer though.

Comment: Isn’t it better to use `getline(‘.’)[col-2]` that way i dont have to take my cursor back to the `.` to press Tab